# Cannot log in to session after update with gdm3

Tags: login, gdm, display-manager, 23.04

I was running Regolith (an i3-based WM) with Ubuntu 22.10.
I just updated my laptop to Ubuntu 23.04 using the `do-release-upgrade`.

After booting, I could access the login session (which is GDM), but after entering my password, the UI components disappear and only let the grey unanimated background. After this step, I am forced to shut down my computer.

- I used the recovery mode to reinstall `gdm3`, but this lead to the same behaviour.
- I installed `lightdm` while waiting to resolve this issue (also I have resolution problem with `lightdm`).
- From an article, I also tried to enable debug logging in `/etc/gdm3/default.conf`. But the `/var/log/gdm3` folder is empty after retrying `gdm3`.
- I tried `gdm3` with other `WM` like `ubuntu-desktop` or `gnome` instead of `regolith-desktop` but I still get the grey screen.

Maybe I'm wrong on the component that causes the issue.
I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Of the 3 solutions proposed, switching to `lightdm` is not really what I want, even though I can find a pretty theme (I fixed the resolution issue by adding the right resolution to grub config). The other 2 solution, booting from `Xorg` and deleting `.Xauthority` lead to the same grey screen.

Comment: I retracted my close vote and your question's status is back to normal again.